# What I need to add to this SQL instruction to filter some items?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want is to filter (not get) offers that appear in this new table, which we use like a black list (i.e., for the domain X we dont want offers with origin Y).

```
TABLE:      black_list_deals

COLUMNS: id 
         domain_id (we save here an id from the table "domain")
         origin_offer (we save here a value from deal, the field deal_source_id)
```

Until now I was using this instruction, but now I need to add the new behaviour to filter depending of the blacklist table to filter these offers.

```
SELECT
    a.lat,
    a.lon,
    a.id,
    a.image,
    a.link,
    a.deal_source_id,
    a.date_posted,
    a.date_expires,
    a.tags_external,
    a.tags_internal,
    a.gender,
    a.price,
    a.discount,
    a.areas,
    a.hits,
    a.bias,
    a.collection_type,
    a.uniqueness,
    a.date_posted = current_date AS today,
    DATEDIFF( a.date_expires, current_date) AS days_remaining,
    a.collection_type,
    b.id AS area_id,
    b.area,
    a.image_thumb,
    c.source_img_email,
    c.source_price,
    c.source_img_sm,
    c.source_name,
    c.frame,
    a.date_posted = current_date AS today,
    d.country,
    d.region,
    e.level1,
    e.level2,
    e.level3,
    e.level4

FROM deal a
      LEFT JOIN area b ON (a.areas = b.id)
      LEFT JOIN deal_source c ON (a.deal_source_id = c.id)
      LEFT JOIN deal_travel d ON (a.id = d.deal_id)
      LEFT JOIN deal_travel_country e ON (d.country = e.id)
WHERE
      a.validated = 'y' AND
      a.date_posted = current_date AND
      a.date_expires >= current_date AND
      email_deal = '1'
```

Comment: Should we guess what table(s) `black_list_deals` relates to? `domain_id` and `origin_offer` don't appear in any of the other tables.

Comment: ok........yes, you're right, the problem is that our database dont use relations (yes....kill us), Im going to modify the description to add that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `WHERE a.deal_source_id NOT IN (SELECT origin_offer FROM black_list_deals)` to your WHERE clause should solve this.

Comment: in the where clause I added something like this, can work? (I will have data tomorrow to test it in the office):


 AND   a.deal_source_id NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM black_list_deals where source_id=a.deal_source_id)

Comment: No, you'll get an error because black_list_deals doesn't have a source_id field. If the black_list_deals.origin_offer field is made up of values from deal.deal_source_id, than syntax above will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would add

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM deal a
...
   LEFT JOIN black_list_deals bld ON (bld.origin_offer = a.deal_source_id)
...
WHERE
...
   AND bld.id IS NULL
```

basically you will return only the data for which an entry in the black list is not found